# Adding Icons to Yii2 Navbar

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

I am fairly new to Yii2 and I am currently building a basic navbar with the built-in widget. The only issue that I am having with this is that I am not sure how to add icons next to the relevant menu options. My current navbar looks like this:

```
  NavBar::begin([
  'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/images/logo.png', ['alt'=>Yii::$app->name,'style'=>'height: 50px; width: 171px; top: 15px; left: 50px; position: absolute;']),
  'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
  'options' => [
      'class' => 'navbar navbar-fixed-top',
  ],
 ]);
echo Nav::widget([
  'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav','style'=>'padding-left:45%;padding-top:35px;'],
  'items' => [
      ['label' => 'How It Works', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
      ['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
      ['label' => 'Pricing', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
      ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
      '<li class="line" style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:10px;">|</li>',
      // '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" style="right:70px;top:7px;"></i>',
      '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="right:70px;top:7px;"></i>',
      Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? (
          ['label' => 'Login','class'=>'login', 'url' => ['/site/login'],]
      ) : (
          '<li>'
          . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
          . Html::submitButton(
              'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
              ['class' => 'btn btn-link logout']
          )
          . Html::endForm()
          . '</li>'
      )
  ],
]);
NavBar::end();
```

As you can see here, I am adding the lock icon and positioning it next to the login option. Is there a way for me to embed that icon within the link so they will react the same to hover? I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
<a href="/site/login"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>Login</a>.
```

But I currently have:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="right:70px;top:7px;"></i>
<a href="/site/login">Login</a>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i understand that you want to display a lock icon in the navigation along the login text like below

[image]

If that is correct you are not adding the icon at the correct place you should add the icon html inside the `label` property and then set `'encodeLabels' => false,` in the `Nav` widget.

Your code should look like below

```
NavBar::begin(
    [
        'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/images/logo.png', ['alt' => Yii::$app->name, 'style' => 'height: 50px; width: 171px; top: 15px; left: 50px; position: absolute;']),
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar navbar-fixed-top'
        ]
    ]
);
echo Nav::widget(
    [
        'encodeLabels' => false,
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav', 'style' => 'padding-left:45%;padding-top:35px;'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'How It Works', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
            ['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
            ['label' => 'Pricing', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
            '<li class="line" style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:10px;">|</li>',
            Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? (
                ['label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>&nbsp;Login', 'class' => 'login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
            ) : (
                '<li>'
                . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
                . Html::submitButton(
                    'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    ['class' => 'btn btn-link logout']
                )
                . Html::endForm()
                . '</li>'
            )
        ]
    ]
);
NavBar::end();
```